# atomのplain textで選択した箇所にマーカーを引きたい

Tags: atom-editor

atomでメモをとるときに重要な箇所にマーカーで線を引きたいと思ったのですが，
何かいいパッケージはありませんか？

Comment: AtomのDecoration APIのためのデモパッケージ [atom/decoration-example](https://github.com/atom/decoration-example) がなかなかにそれっぽいのですが、これに類似するパッケージをまだ見つけられていません。あるいはこれを参考にしてご自身で書かれても良いかもしれません。ご参考までに。

Answer (score 1):

**quick-highlight**というパッケージはどうでしょう？
http://qiita.com/t9md/items/a529b06e26cc9fe33f70